# Hot reload and hot restart of flutter on android studio disabled on physical device

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Hot reload and hot restart works fine on emulator but doesnot work on my physical device Samsung Galaxy s9+ (Android 10 Q).

I tried:

- Updating platform tools to latest version
- Android Q was ready to update so updated it.
- Restarted android studio and system.

[Hot reload and hot restart greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llaVa.png)

Note: Also installing for the first time, when auto opened by android studio, screen is blank. I have to close the app and re open it to see the layout.

Comment: Which version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: Latest version of flutter via flutter upgrade 1.20.4